# Adjacent Selector for image links

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="pix/gross/aa.jpg"><img src="pix/klein/aa.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="pix/gross/bb.jpg"><img src="pix/klein/bb.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="pix/gross/cc.jpg"><img src="pix/klein/cc.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="pix/gross/dd.jpg"><img src="pix/klein/dd.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Now I want to add a margin to all images except the first. When I remove the `<a>` tags the following css works fine:

```
.row img + img {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

But when I add `<a>` the css doesn't work. So how can I add the anchor element to the css?

Answer (score 2):

Well, when they're in links, they're not adjacent anymore. The links are, though:

```
.row a + a {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ecAdudA/1) *(with exaggerated margin)* | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ecAdudA/1/edit)

Comment: Jep your are right - I missed the forrest for the trees :-). But nevertheless when I want to select only the linked images?

Comment: @FranzGsell: Isn't that `.row a + a img`? http://jsbin.com/ecAdudA/3/edit (I've added borders to make it clear which element is which)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.row a:not(:first-child) img{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Jfw7/)